# How to stop hibernate from inserting into a table in ManyToMany Mapping?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many

Problem: My web MVC app is inserting into the ingredient Table. I do not want this because I have already populated that table with 1000 different shampoo ingredients.

I did try messing with the "cascade=CascadeType.ALL" setting but I usually got " object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.app.entity.Ingredient". But I am really not sure if that would even fix anything.

[Image of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQSnf.png)

[DB DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKCxD.png)

**toString() output after results user submission and before being inserted into DB:**

```
Shampoo [id=0, name=sas, company=Company [id=0, name=asassa], ingredients=[Ingredient [id=0, name=1-Dodecene, shampoos=null], Ingredient [id=0, name=Acetylated, shampoos=null]]]
```

**Hibernate Stuff:**

```
Hibernate: insert into company (company_name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into shampoo (shampoo_company, shampoo_name) values (?, ?)
```

> ```
> Hibernate: insert into ingredient (ingredient_name) values (?)
> Hibernate: insert into ingredient (ingredient_name) values (?)
> ```
>
> I do not want it to be inserting into ingredient table because I have already populated the table with 1000 ingredient names. Realistically I would just want to insert into shampoo_ingredients with the key of the given ingredient.

```
Hibernate: insert into shampoo_ingredients (fk_shampoo, fk_ingredient) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into shampoo_ingredients (fk_shampoo, fk_ingredient) values (?, ?)
```

**Shampoo Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="shampoo")
public class Shampoo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="shampoo_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="shampoo_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="shampoo_company")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="shampoo_ingredients",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_shampoo"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_ingredient")
            )
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    public Shampoo() {

    }



    public Shampoo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }


    public List<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shampoo [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", company=" + company + ", ingredients=" + ingredients + "]";
    }


}
```

**Ingredient Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ingredient")
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ingredient_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="ingredient_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="shampoo_ingredients",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_ingredient"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="fk_shampoo")
            )
    private List<Shampoo> shampoos;

    public Ingredient() {

    }


    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public List<Shampoo> getShampoos() {
        return shampoos;
    }

    public void setShampoos(List<Shampoo> shampoos) {
        this.shampoos = shampoos;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ingredient [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", shampoos=" + shampoos + "]";
    }


}
```

**Shampoo Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shampoo")
public class ShampooController {

    //inject DAO into controller
    @Autowired
    private ShampooDAO shampooDAO;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyDAO companyDAO;
    @Autowired
    private IngredientDAO ingredientDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ConversionService cs;
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listShampoos(Model theModel) {

        //get shampoo from DAO
        List<Shampoo> theShampoos = shampooDAO.getShampoos();

        //add shampoo to model
        theModel.addAttribute("shampoos", theShampoos);
        return "list-shampoos";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel, ModelMap modelMap) {
        //create model attribute to bind form data

        Shampoo theShampoo = new Shampoo();
        modelMap.addAttribute("shampoo", theShampoo);


        List<Ingredient> theIngredients = ingredientDAO.getIngredients();

        modelMap.addAttribute("ingredient", theIngredients);




        return "shampoo-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveShampoo")
    public String saveShampoo(@ModelAttribute("shampoo") Shampoo theShampoo) {


        System.out.println(theShampoo.getIngredients());
        System.out.println(theShampoo.toString());
        shampooDAO.saveShampoo(theShampoo);
        return "redirect:/shampoo/list";

    }
}
```

**Shampoo DAO**

```
@Repository
public class ShampooDAOImpl implements ShampooDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public List<Shampoo> getShampoos() {

        //get current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //create query
        Query<Shampoo> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Shampoo", Shampoo.class);
        //execute query and get result list
        List<Shampoo> shampoos = theQuery.getResultList();
        //return list of shampoo
        return shampoos;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveShampoo(Shampoo theShampoo) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        currentSession.save(theShampoo);

    }

}
```

**Shampoo Form**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add New Shampoo</title>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/chosen.jquery.js"></script>


    <link type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e){
    // first initialize the Chosen select
    $('.test').chosen();

});


</script>

</head>
<body>

        <form:form cssClass="form" action="saveShampoo" modelAttribute="shampoo" method="POST">

            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Name:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Company:</label></td>
                        <td><form:input path="company" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Ingredients:</label></td>
                        <td><form:select cssClass="test" multiple="true" path="Ingredients" >
                            <form:options items="${ingredient}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="name" />

                            </form:select></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
            <input id= "submit" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Without looking too close I assume you are inserting a new shampoo but you have to retrieve existing ingredients from the database first before you persist the new shampoo. You will have to look them up and replace them in your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that when you try to join entities shampoo and ingredients you must fetch them from DB.

Let's suppose you create a new shampoo. You can do:

```
Shampoo s = new Shampoo();
//All your own stuffs about Shampoo object
```

Now you want to join shampoo and Ingredients; and let's suppose the name of the ingredients you want to join with it are "IngrA" e "IngrB" you can't do:

```
Ingredient a = new Ingredient();
a.setName("IngrA");
Ingredient b = new Ingredient();
b.setName("IngrB");
List<Ingredient> ingrs = new ArrayList<>(2);
ingrs.add(a);
ingrs.add(b);
s.setIngredients(ingrs);
repository.save(s); //Error will be thrown here; If you have CascadeType.All an insert will be done
```

Why will you have error? Because according Hibernate `a` and `b` are "new" objects you never saved. So hibernate is telling you: "Before you can join them you must save them".

On the other side since you have `CascadeType.All` hibernate tries to insert these "new" objects

What you must do is to search the ingredients in the DB and then set them.

I mean something like this:

```
Ingredient a = ingredientDao.findByName("IngrA");
Ingredient b = ingredientDao.findByName("IngrB");
List<Ingredient> ingrs = new ArrayList<>(2);
if(a!=null)
   ingrs.add(a);
if(b!=null)
   ingrs.add(b);
s.setIngredients(ingrs);
repository.save(s); //No error will be thrown here
```

Why no error? Because you retrieved the ingredients from DB and now they are no more detached.

I hope it's useful

Angelo